# Beat the sword master - minimum required status?

Tags: quest-for-glory-1

I'm playing again Quest for Glory 1.
My status are pretty high, but I still can't beat the Sword Master no matter what!

Here is my character stats:
[image]

I'm also using the chainmail, but I don't think it will influence in any way the fight.

Is there any trick to beat him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per an [old guide](http://www.oocities.org/timessquare/arcade/7435/QFG1/qfg1_FAQ.htm) I found:

- Rest so that your health and stamina are as high as possible before fighting the Swordmaster
- Focus on attacking, defending costs precious stamina that you'd need to push him back with attacks.
- If you are overloaded with equipment, your fighting effectiveness goes down. Try dropping any excess heavy stuff before fighting (this may include the chainmail).

  - *Don't forget to pick it all back up after!*
- The fight may be more difficult at higher speeds; if it isn't already, try setting the game speed to the lowest setting. If it's already at the lowest speed, you might try a utility to lower the CPU speeds (if you are playing through DOSBox, this is done through [DOSBox's settings](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Configuration:CPU))

Comment: I just managed to beat him by [decreasing the dosbox cycles](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Special_Keys) I was fully rested with everything at 100 points. It doesn't matter if you are overloaded with weight and wearing the chainmail. The only thing that I changed between fights was decreasing the cycles and moving the speed lever all the way to the bottom.